# notification dropdown is not over lapping

Tags: html, css, jsp, z-index

I am trying to solve this but can't , I used all types wat I know in this, & tried z-index too not worked
let me know the solution for this. I connected my header to all pages. this issues is in all page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvIG0.png)

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Try increasing the z-index of the header element rather than just the dropdown

Comment: One suggestion I would say from what I can see from the image you provided is to add **position: relative;** to the elements that you want to be behind the dropdown and add to them a z-index less than the z-index of the dropdown.

Comment: Try z-index: 9999;